# What kind of political system do Palestinian political entities want?

Tags: israel, political-system, palestine

What kind of political system do the key players of Palestinian politics (Fatah, Hamas etc.) want to establish, as the next step after a successful resolution of the Palestinian-Israeli conflict?

"Successful resolution" could be a two-state approach, or whatever violent option Hamas wants to pursue, or something else, either way - do these organisation have a properly expressed "step 2" after their raison d'etre isn't entirely opposition to Israel.

Middle Eastern, Arab-majority, Muslim-majority states have political systems varying from theocratic, through secular authoritarian regimes, to fairly democratic ones, I wonder where on that spectrum the current key Palestinian players envisage the prospective Palestinian state.

Comment: Except for geographic division, there are no major dividers between Gaza and the West Bank. Although authoritarian local rule is sometimes enough to create strange divisions see [Nakhchivan](https://www.lemonde.fr/en/international/article/2023/10/20/inside-the-azerbaijan-controlled-nakhchivan-exclave-closed-to-western-media-for-30-years_6191114_4.html).

Comment: I find the closing/reopening somewhat baffling. The original question stated "what would a Palestinian state look like, based on what we know about Hamas / Fatah etc.", then changed to "what do we know about Fatah/Hamas plans for an independent Palestine". Same thing, and both seem like valid questions in Politics.

Comment: @Fizz I'm not lumping Fatah and Hamas into one entity. I am interested in how the key political Palestinian players say they want to organise an independent Palestinian state - a key objective political objectives. I'm interested in both commonalities and differences between different political bodies.

Comment: This looks to be one of those ill-fated questions that overly relies on western worldviews when framing non-western cultures.

Comment: Some might argue that Hamas is in favor of an islamic caliphate, perhaps based on their official covenant. But their rhetoric over the past decade or so illustrates that they believe the battle against Israel and the West is ["the Greatest Battle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Malhama_Al-Kubra), similar to the Armageddon in Christian theology. They believe that there is no such thing as *"after a resolution of the conflict"*. Or at least they seem to act in accordance with this such a belief.